# Is there no way to list directories only using Golang Glob?

Tags: go, glob

Golang Glob doesn't behave the way I expected it to. Let's say I have a directory "foo" with the following structure:

```
foo
|-- 1.txt
|-- 2.csv
|-- 3.json
|-- bar
`-- baz
```

I want to do a glob that gets only the directories "bar" and "baz" within foo. So I try this:

```
path = "foo/*/"
matches, err := filepath.Glob(path)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(matches)
```

This produces no matches:

```
[]
```

If I remove the last trailing slash and change path to `"foo/*"`, I get both files and directories, which is not the result I want:

```
[foo/1.txt foo/2.csv foo/3.json foo/bar foo/baz]
```

I would expect that if a trailing slash is present, Glob would return only directories that match the glob pattern. I see that the same issue is [noted on GitHub](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33617), but couldn't see any workaround for it - it sounds either like a bug, a poorly documented feature, or simply a lack of an expected feature.

[I've checked the Go docs for the Match function](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match), which Glob uses, and it doesn't mention anything about a trailing slash.

So basically: is there a workaround so that I can glob only directories under a certain path using Glob, or do I need to use another method for this task?

Comment: "Glob returns the names of all _files_ matching pattern"; it appears the function is doing exactly as it says. The workaround would be to filter the results or write a glob function which works the way you want it to.

Comment: Would the path `/foo/*/.` work?

Comment: @rsp It seems not - that also returns nothing `[]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate through the list of matches and call os.Stat on each of them. os.Stat returns a FileInfo structure describing the file and it includes a method called IsDir for checking if a file is a directory.
Sample code:

```golang
// Note: Ignoring errors.
matches, _ := filepath.Glob("foo/*")
var dirs []string
for _, match := range matches {
    f, _ := os.Stat(match)
    if f.IsDir() {
        dirs = append(dirs, match)
    }
}
```